# authorizeSecurityGroupIngress neither add rule, nor does it fail

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2

in the callback of `createSecurityGroup` i try to add some rules to the new security group. the call to `authorizeSecurityGroupIngress`does not fail (i.e. `err` is null), but the rules do not appear in the "inbound" tab of the security group when i check in the AWS console.

here is a stripped down version of my code:

```
var createSecurityGroupParams = {
    GroupName   : "webserver-default",
    VpcId       : Vpc.VpcId, // a valid vpc id
    Description : "..."
};

ec2.createSecurityGroup(createSecurityGroupParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { /* error handling */}

    var authorizeSecurityGroupIngressParams = {
        GroupId    : data.GroupId,
        IpProtocol : "tcp",
        ToPort     : 22,
        CidrIp     : "0.0.0.0/0"
    };

    ec2.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(authorizeSecurityGroupIngressParams, function(err, data) {
        if (err) { /* error handling... never called */ }
    });
});
```

thx in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

looks like i used a wrong combination of request parameters. changing `authorizeSecurityGroupIngressParams` like this solved the problem:

```
var authorizeSecurityGroupIngressParams = {
    GroupId: data.GroupId,
    IpPermissions: [{
        IpProtocol: "tcp",
        FromPort: 22,
        ToPort: 22,
        IpRanges: [{
            CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
        }]
    }]
};
```

still do not know why the last version did not fail with a error.